# $f$ continuous $\Rightarrow$ $f$ $\mu$ measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions, outer-measure

Let $f: X\to [0,\infty]$ be a continuous function and $\mu$ an outer measure on X.
For a continuous function I can split it in a sum of step functions, so $$ f(x) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty s_i \chi_{A_i} $$ Is $f$ also $\mu$ measurable and therefore Lebesgue integrable?

If not can you give me an example? I am not even sure if the splitting is possible for every continuous function.

**Edit:**
I see that splitting isn't possible for every continuous function. After reading a bit in my notes of my lecture, I cant see why I can argument that a function $f$ is $\mu$ measurable if it is continuous.
Has someone an explaining or a hint so I can try the prove myself?

Comment: the split is not possible for all continuous functions, by example consider the function $f(x)=x$

Comment: Well, I guess my problem is that I cant see why continuous function on X should be $\mu$ measurable and therefore Lebesgue integrable.  I guess I am missing something.

Comment: any measurable function can be approximated by a simple function. See [here](https://www3.nd.edu/~math/restricted/CourseArchive/300Level/366/3662001S/Lectures/12.LebesgueIntegral.pdf) theorem 4

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to MSE!

We need a little bit of bonus information -- $X$ must be a topological space to make sense of continuous functions, and $X$ must *also* be equipped with a $\sigma$-algebra to make sense of measurable functions.

In order for continuity to imply measurability, these two structures must be compatible (in which case $\mu$ is called a [borel measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_measure)). Without this constraint, things can go wrong. For instance if $X$ is equipped with the discrete topology, then *every* function is continuous. As an exercise, you might try to use this idea to find an explicit example of a space $X$ equipped with a topology and a $\sigma$-algebra so that some continuous function is not measurable.

Ok, so with the pedantic caveat out of the way, let's try to see why (for borel measures) a continuous function is automatically measurable. Here's a hint:

Let's look at the definitions of measurable and continuous functions.

- $f$ is **continuous** whenever $f^{-1}((a,b)) \subseteq X$ is *open* for every $(a,b) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.
- $f$ is **measurable** whenever $f^{-1}((a,b)) \subseteq X$ is *measurable* for every $(a,b) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

So to show continuous $\Rightarrow$ measurable, it suffices to show that every open subset of $X$ is measurable (do you see why?). Can you use our assumption that $\mu$ is a borel measure to finish up?

---

I hope this helps ^_^